# How do I create recursive template in xslt

Tags: xslt, recursion, xslt-1.0

I have a sharepoint list which is designed like below. Here is a sample data of input.

```
Name     ID  Navigation_URL ParentID IsShow 
Test1    1  #               0        Yes
Test2    2  #               0        Yes
Test2.1  3  #               2        Yes
Test2.1.14  #               3        Yes
```

How to create an unordered list using xslt function.
Output should be like:

```
<ul>
<li>Test1</li>
<li>Test2
    <ul>
        <li>Test2.1
              <ul>
                   <li>Test2.1.1</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about SharePoint, I can only help you with the XSLT part. Once you have an XML document such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <Item>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ParentID>0</ParentID>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ParentID>0</ParentID>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Test2.1</Name>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <ParentID>2</ParentID>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>Test2.1.1</Name>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <ParentID>3</ParentID>
  </Item>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-parent" match="Item" use="ParentID" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[ParentID='0']"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('item-by-parent', ID)" />
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:if test="$children">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$children"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will transform it to:

**Result**

```
<ul>
   <li>Test1</li>
   <li>Test2<ul>
         <li>Test2.1<ul>
               <li>Test2.1.1</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

---

### Edit:

> One thing is missed isShow ... It's a node/column based on which I can
>   exclude or not show that corresponding item

You could just add another template:

```
<xsl:template match="Item[IsShow='No']"/>
```

This is assuming that excluding an item is also supposed to exclude its descendants.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.I will adopt it to sharepoint.One thing is missed  isShow for which some xsl:if has to be applied.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What is the significance of  `isShow`?

Comment: It's a node/column based on which I can exclude or not show that corresponding item